# iOS ScrollView won't scroll initial load

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

On viewWillAppear a URL request is made, the data is stored in SQLite, then the function is called to generate the list.  The same function is called on the initial load, as the buttons/tabs above the list, but the initial load won't scroll, while clicking the buttons, recalling the generateList, makes the scroll work.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", @"www.URL.com/", @"extension";
    NSLog(@"Log: %@", url);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection){
        //connected
    }else{
        //failed
    }
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    //response defined in synthesize
    response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSString *extension = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", connection.currentRequest];
    if(extension == @"list"){
        ...load into sqlite after deleting old data...
        [self generateList:0]
    }
}
- (IBAction)TabOne:(id)sender {
    ...style buttons...
    [self generateList:1];
}

-(void)generateList:(int)tabNum{
    // --- Problem Area ---
    // To Top of List
    [self.ListScroll setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
    // Remove any List subviews
    [[self.List subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    ...query sqlite and load content into UIView inside UIScrollView which the NSLog shows is working...
    // Resize List
    self.List.frame = CGRectMake(self.List.frame.origin.x, self.List.frame.origin.y, self.List.frame.size.width, (rowCount) *51);
    self.ListScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.List.frame.size.width, self.List.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"height: %f", self.List.frame.size.height);// Returns Correct
    NSLog(@"height: %f", self.ListScroll.contentSize.height);// Returns Correct
}
```

Side Note: In the storyboard I have the UIView inside the UIScrollView height set to 9,999, because interacting with buttons that go outside those initial bounds fails to function.

I greatly appreciate any and all help and criticism to solve this problem and improve this code.  You are all awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was to create the UIScrollView and inner UIView programmatically, instead of using the Storyboards.  If someone has a solution for using storyboards, I am sure others would appreciate it.